# How to configure a new host and virtual machine on opennebula?

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, opennebula

We're using OpenNebula to simulate a simple replicated `JBoss` application.

We've installed all opennebula packages, qemu and kvm and libvirt.

We have created a simple ethernet network ad hoc between my pc (a node) and the one of my friend (which is both node and front-end) by plugging an ethernet cable between me and him (10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2).

So we can ping each other correctly, we've set everything to that we can ssh without a password to each other with "oneadmin" user.

We've configured all files such as below:

```
/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf
/etc/default/libvirtd-bin
```

And so on...
kvm and kvm-intel are both enabled.
The daemon 
    libvirtd -d -l
seems to start correctly.

In fact, from the gui of opennebula in the front end, we can see both the hosts monitored.

Anyway there's a problem when we try to start the virtual machine on the node which is not the front-end. I mean when we try to do a deploy of a VM on the other node. The error is something like this

```
cannot stat `/var/lib/one/datastores/1/f5394317d377beaa09fc07697df9ff68
```

but if, from the front end which has virtual machine n°1 we perform,
    cd /var/lib/one/datastores/1
then we can see that file, we've also given all the permissions to it...
Any idea? :(

Answer (score 0):

This may be related with the datastore configuration. If you left the default values, OpenNebula expects a shared filesystem (ie NFS) between the front-end and the virtualization nodes.

More context on the error (which I believe can be found in /var/lib/one/oned.log) would help analysing this problem.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: Sorry about that folks, and thanks Radim for pointing that out to me. Vitor, without the log I can only guess, but datastore misconfiguration would be my bet. My $0.02.